# Moving existing django objects along the model inheritance chain

Tags: python, django

We know that Django [allows us to use model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance). But I was wondering if it is possible to move an existing instance of a given model along the inheritance chain after it has been created, all the while preserving the integrity of the application.

Example (from the official docs):

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So, if I have an existing instance which is a `Place` and I want to make it a `Restaurant`, is there a way to do that safely?

I'm using Django 1.7, Python 3.4

Comment: awesome question, I'm going to do some playing around...

Comment: @awwester Thank you. I was reluctant to ask, because I wasn't sure my premise is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the downcast i've found solution like that

```
restaurant = Restaurant(place_ptr_id=place.id)
restaurant.__dict__.update(place.__dict__)
restaurant.save()
```